# elif condition in an if statement

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, variable

I have this variables

```
start=$1;
end=$2;
sn=${#start}
en=${#end}
```

and this if :

```
if ( [ $# -eq 2 ] )
then
elif ( [ $sn -ne 3 ] && [ -n "$(printf '%s\n' "$start" | sed 's/[0-9]//g') " ] );
then     
    echo "Incorrect format"
    exit 1
elif ( [ $en -ne 3 ] && [ -n "$(printf '%s\n' "$end" | sed 's/[0-9]//g') " ] );
then
    echo "Incorrect format"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Correct format"
    exit 1
fi
```

and I get unexpected at the first elif , I want to check the arguments provided by the user and they have to be made by only 3 digits .

Comment: another plug for shellcheck.net here

Comment: What is the input that causes your unexpected results, what results are you actually getting, and what results do you want?

Comment: I want to have the incorrect format echo on the screen if the provided variables are not 2 digits like 11 , 12 , 55 and echo that the format is correct if there are only 2 digits provided for both arguments .

Comment: You have said you want them to be 3 digits in your question and that you want them to be 2 digits in a comment.  Please clarify.

Comment: sorry indeed is about 3 digits , the number of arguments is 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( [ $# -eq 2 ] )
then
elif
```

As Jeff's answer says, the first `if` condition is missing the part with the commands. The error messages given by Bash and Dash are a bit vague, it seems like they come directly from the parser, and they haven't bothered to add a more user-friendly message there.

If you don't want to do anything inside a branch, you'll still need to add some command there. I'd suggest `true`, which doesn't do anything.

Fixing that, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) gives a couple of more observations:

```
if ( [ $# -eq 2 ] )
   ^-- SC2233: Remove superfluous (..) around condition.
```

The parenthesis start a subshell, which is not necessary here (and involves extra overhead, like forking a subprocess in Bash).

```
... [ -n "$(printf '%s\n' "$start" | sed 's/[0-9]//g') " ] 
>>                                                    ^-- 
             SC2157: Argument to -n is always true due to literal strings.
```

You've quoted the command substitution, good! But you have an extra space there in the end. Whatever the command substitution outputs, the argument to `-n` will never be empty, because of that space.

(It also notes about quoting `$sn` and `$en`, which would be the careful thing to do, but isn't really necessary if you know `IFS` doesn't contain any digits.)

---

That said, I'm not sure the conditions still are quite right. You say:

> I want to check the arguments provided by the user and they have to be made by only 3 digits .

But note that the test below catches only the case where `sn` is not three, *and in addition* there are other characters than numbers, i.e. it passes `abc` and `1234`, and only rejects, say `abcd`. You want an *or* condition, `||`, instead of *and*.

```
if [ $sn -ne 3 ] && [ -n "$(printf '%s\n' "$start" | sed 's/[0-9]//g')" ]; then
    echo reject
```

Or you could just use `case` and a pattern match:

```
case "$start" in
    [0-9][0-9][0-9]) echo "'$start' is ok";;
    *) echo "'$start' is invalid"; exit 1;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you very much , using the case statement helped !

Comment: Or, with bash, `if [[ $start != [0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then die; fi` -- within double brackets, the `==` and `!=` operators are *pattern matching*

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any statements in the "true" case of your first `if`:

```
if ( [ $# -eq 2 ] )

then
  ##  <-- HERE
elif  ...
```

Quoting the bash manual:

> The syntax of the if command is:
>
> ```
> if test-commands; then
>   consequent-commands;
> [elif more-test-commands; then
>   more-consequents;]
> [else alternate-consequents;]
> fi
> ```

Where the important bit is the `consequent-commands`.

Comment: After updating the statement no check is done on the provided variables .

Comment: @bboy:  That's because you likely don't want to check if there are two arguments, you probably want to check if there is **not** two arguments.

Comment: Specifically, when using `if`, you have to do _something_ if the test returns something truthy.  If you only want to act when the result is falsy, you must either add a no-op to the consequent-commands, or flip the logic of the test:  Either `if test; then :; else thing; fi` or `if ! test; then thing; fi`.  The same holds true for `elif`.